# I want to use Provider in InitState() but got an exception: Null check operator used on a null value

Tags: flutter

Hi I'm new to flutter.

I am using Provider and want to use the data I get from it as the initial value of textfield. So I decided to define the controller as a nullable value and put the text to it in `initState()`.

Here is the code.

```
...
TextEditingController? _lastNameController;
TextEditingController? _firstNameController;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
   WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
    MyProvider myProvider = Provider.of(context, listen : false);
    _lastNameController  = TextEditingController(text : myProvider.lastName);
    _firstNameController = TextEditingController(text : myProvider.firstName);
  });
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Row(
    children : [
      // this is an extension of TextField
      MyTextField(controller : _lastNameController!,  hintText : 'Last Name'),
      const Spacer(),
      MyTextField(controller : _firstNameController!, hintText : 'First Name')
...
```

And I got an exception `Null check operator used on a null value`.

Please let me know if you have any solution.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback` will calls after the 1st frame is build. So initially `MyTextField` is getting null from both `_lastNameController` and `_firstNameController`.

You can do

```dart
 MyTextField(controller : _lastNameController??TextEditingController(),
```

or

```dart
if(_lastNameController!=null) MyTextField(controller : _lastNameController,
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer.
I tried it, but I got textfields with empty values.

Comment: call setState end of `addPostFrameCallback`

Comment: glad to help, you can find more about [addPostFrameCallback](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/scheduler/SchedulerBinding/addPostFrameCallback.html)